# Click on an object, get another object?

Tags: javascript, jquery

On click I get an objects id.

The id will be something like 'about-me'.

Now in the on click function I want to target the object that's called 'content-about-me'.

How can I do this? Ive tried this with no luck:

```
$('.sub-nav').on('click', function(){

        $('#content-'$(this).attr('id'));

    });
```

Comment: Can you please post your HTML?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to concatenate the id with the prefix `content-`:

```
$('#content-' + this.id);
```

I also replaced `$(this).attr('id')` with the equivalent but shorter `this.id`.

Keep in mind that instead of doing this, it might be a good idea to have the full id of the "other" element stored somewhere on the click target. For example:

```
<div class="sub-nav" id="foo" data-other-element="content-foo">...</div>
```

And then do

```
$('.sub-nav').on('click', function(){
    var $other = $("#" + $(this).attr('data-other-element-'));
});
```

This code is [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), so if you decide to change the id tagging scheme your JS code will not need to change as well.